# Say $f(x)$ is differential at $x=a$, can I prove it does not diverge at $x=a$?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

There exists a theorem saying that if $f(x)$ is differential at $(a,b)$, it's continuous in $(a,b)$ right? But how come we can't say anything if it's differential only in 1 point?

Given that there exists:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(0)$$

And that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = f'(0)$$

And there exists a series $0 < x_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{ } 0$ such that:

$$ f(x_{n+1}) \cdot f(x_n) < 0 $$

I need to prove that:

$$f(0) = f'(0) = 0$$

Given $x_n$, I can prove that for any $L \neq 0$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) \neq L $$

Which means that $f(x)$ is either essentially discontinuous at $x=0$ or that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0 $, right? How can I prove using the derivation at $x=0$ that $f(0) = 0$ ? or that at least $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Do you know something more about $f$? continuous? something? For me it is not cclear what are you asking for.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and *therefore* it is continuous at $0$. Regardless of $L$, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies :) Because of the fact that there exists $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = f'(0)$, $f(x)$ is differential somewhere near $x=0$? Is it just obvious? Is there anything here to prove?

Comment: @TitoEliatron , no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is derivable at $x=0$, then it is continuous, hence, sequentially continuous.

Now $f(x_{n+1})f(x_n)<0$ implies (taking $n\to\infty$) that $f(0)^2\le0$, whence $f(0)=0$.

On the other hand, The condition $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=f'(0)$ implies,in particular, that there is $\delta>0$ such that $f'(x)$ exists on $[0,\delta)$, so $f$ is continuous on $[0,\delta)$.

AS $x_n\to0$, ther is $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in[0,\delta)$ for $n\ge N$.

Now, for $n\ge N$ you know that $f$ is continuous on $[x_{n+1},x_n]$ and that $f(x_{n+1})f(x_n)<0$. Bolzano says that there is $x_{n+1}<c_n<x_n$ such that $f(c_n)=0$. Obserrve that $(c_n)_n$ is also decreasing.

$f$ is continuous at $[c_{n+1},c_n]$, derivable at $(c_{n+1},c_n)$ and $f(c_n)=f(c_{n+1})=0$. Lagrange says that ther is $c_{n+1}<d_n<c_n$ such that $f'(d_n)=0$.

Finally, $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(d_n)=0$.

Comment: Oh right... So the most important fact is that $f'(x)$ is continuous right?

Comment: And BTW what about $f'(0)$?

Comment: I have a problem with the statement that $f$ derivable at $x=0$ implies that it's continuous - Once in class they've showed us $f(x)$ that equals $x^2$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $-x^2$ for any $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$. This function is derivable at $x=0$ but not continuous at all at any other point.

Comment: $f(x)-f(0)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\cdot x \to f'(0)\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure why Bolzano was needed here - if $x_{n+1} < c_n < x_n$ and $c_{n+1} < d_n < c_n $ then according to the squeeze theorem (twice) $c_n  \to 0$ and hence $d_n \to 0$.

Comment: You need Bolzano to assure that $f(c_n)=0$, in order to apply then Lagrange.